# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror

Does anyone know why I would be getting an error like this?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I would really appreciate it if you do, I am new to this and trying to learn, but I'm getting really caught up in the nitty gritty of Python!

Code:

```
for test in test_set:
 person_id = test['person_id']
 place_id = test['place_id']
 rating = test['rating']
 predicted_rating = simple_nn(person_id, place_id, 5)
 #difference =  (rating - predicted_rating)
 sq_err = (rating - predicted_rating) * (rating - predicted_rating)

 sq_err_sum = sq_err 
   
 sq_err_sum = sq_err_sum + sq_err
    
 rmse = math.sqrt(sq_err_sum/5)
 print rmse
```

Comment: it's a function I got from a book, its calculating similarity I think, that function works perfectly but as I said I did not write it myself unfortunately

Comment: Post the function please

Answer (score 15):

Judging by what you've provided, and the error this is my conclusion.

The only place you use the `-` operand is in the two points

```
sq_err = (rating- predicted_rating) * (rating - predicted_rating)
```

because the error states `'float' and 'NoneType'` we can conclude that `rating` is type `float` and `predicted_rating` is `NoneType`.

You defined `predicted_rating` as:

```
predicted_rating = simple_nn(person_id, place_id, 5)
```

So this means that somewhere in your code for the function `simple_nn` you are not returning anything. Perhaps if you used conditions you didn't evaluate every end path and the function simply returned.

for example... all of these functions return the None type.

```
def example1():
    pass

def example2():
    return

def example3(a = True, b  = True):
    if not a:
        return True
    elif not b:
        return False
```

Note in the last example there is a path where neither if case is satisfied,.. thus it could return None

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to add

```
return
```

to the computed expression in the function definition.

Example:

```
def drift(y, t): theta*(mu-y)  # define OUP drift term
def diffusion(y, t): sigma  # define OUP diffusion term
```

will return the type 'None' when called,

where as,

```
def drift(y, t): return theta*(mu-y)  # define OUP drift term
def diffusion(y, t): return sigma  # define OUP diffusion term
```

will return actual numbers

Answer (score 1):

you can also use import division

> from _ _ future _ _ import division

it worked for me in same case

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem as well when working with openpyxl; the operand * was supposed to change the value of the cells in the worksheet. This solution worked for me; the error was because of the cells with a None value. Adding the code below solved the issue:

```
if cell.value:
    corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
else:
    corrected_price = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

During debug I realized that for me some column values were Nan, just incase it might be the same case for you. You could try the below snippet drops nan records.

```
df = df.dropna()
```