# Don't understand this TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anomaly-detection

I'm getting unsupported operand type error. I know this means that somewhere in my code , i am not returning anything but where i dont know. Could you please help me to solve this?

```py
def explain_anomalies(y, window_size, sigma=1.0):

    avg = moving_average(y, window_size).tolist()
    residual = y - avg

    std = np.std(residual)
    return {'standard_deviation': round(std, 3),
            'anomalies_dict': collections.OrderedDict([(index, y_i) for 
                                                       index, y_i, avg_i in 
    zip(count(), y, avg)
              if (y_i > avg_i + (sigma*std)) | (y_i < avg_i - (sigma*std))])}
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/tcckaya/Documents/python/Kurs/anomaly_detect_zip1.py", line 72, in <listcomp>
    if (y_i > avg_i + (sigma*std)) | (y_i < avg_i - (sigma*std))])}

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: You absolutely need to [edit] your question to fix the formatting errors. On the desktop version of the site, paste your code and then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K. Ditto for the traceback.

Comment: can you print y_i and avg_i before the last statement?

Comment: I guess changing to `y_i > (avg_i + (sigma * std))` should solve the problem.

Comment: Examine the lists you `zip`; do they contain `None`?

Comment: @Vishal  i tried your advise but i got the same error :


  File "C:/Users/tcckaya/Documents/python/Kurs/anomaly_detect_zip1.py", line 72, in <listcomp>
    if (y_i > (avg_i + (sigma*std))) | (y_i < (avg_i - (sigma*std)))])}

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType' python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037408/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-nonetype-python)

Comment: @tripleee  how can i check this ? i am trying to replicate this article ; they ve used izip in Python 2.7 but i changed it to zip function regarding to the changes in itertools in Python 3.7.

https://www.datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection

Comment: Then I guess `avg_i` contains None. You can do like this `if (  (avg_i is not None) and ( y_i > avg_i + (sigma*std)) | (y_i < avg_i - (sigma*std)))`

Comment: So, `avg_i is None`, thus, `avg` is a list of `None`s. On the other hand, you shouldn't have been able to subtract the _list_ `avg` from whatever `y` is, because you can't normally subtract lists from stuff. Moreover, if `avg` contained `None`s, as it does according to the error message, you should've gotten an error while subtracting one of these `None`s from `y`. Is this the _exact_ code you're running?

Comment: Printing the lists would be a good start.